# Missing vignettes for GA package in CRAN

Tags: r, cran

When I go to http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/index.html it has vignettes listed but they both just pull up a blank PDF.  I've looked around at different snapshots on archive.org but can't find them.  Does anyone know if they ever existed or if CRAN is just mistaken about their existence?

Comment: The source of the vignettes seems to be empty. I suggest you contact the package maintainer listed on the CRAN entry. That's probably the only person who will know for sure.